# Product Rewrite

Tags: url-rewrite

Hi is this normal i have my product url to rewrite, When the link is intitially clicked i get a nice clean URL as below

http://www.stickerstocker.co.uk/learning-resources-soft-foam-sight-words-cubes-set-of-6.html

but then once the page begins to load i get the following

http://www.stickerstocker.co.uk/learning-resources-soft-foam-sight-words-cubes-set-of-6.html#.VOYQKPmsXkE

It only happens with my product URLS, is this normal. Does it affect my SEO in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mattee77,This occur due to social share JavaScript code.just remove it ....It will be working properly

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-534db2f331ef025a"></script>` this reason